# Default row values if returned row is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I have a sample query below:

```
Select column1, column2, column3
from table1
where column1 = 3
```

and the result is blank

[image]

Question: How to update the query that it will return this default result instead of blank rows?

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no rows found |  |  |

I tried a case expression but its still returning a blank row

Comment: Does blank mean NULL or an empty string? Be precise please and include what you tried that's not working.

Comment: `select case when column1 = ':----' then 'no wanted value found' else column1 end` because `:----` isn't NULL and "blank" still seems to produce 1 row of output so "no rows found" is an inaccurate statement

Comment: just ignore the  :------: as there will be no row returned where column1 = 3. see screenshot below.

Comment: So there is *no* row? Not even a `NULL` or empty string (`''`)? No row returned is *not* the same as a "blank row"; how can a row be blank when it doesn't exist?

Comment: i updated the question with the screenshot of the returned row

Comment: There are no rows in that image... The columns headers *aren't* a row. So what values are you expecting these columns when there are no rows in the table? What  are the data types of your columns `column1`, `column2` and `column3`?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK I think, this is one of the rare cases where image might make senses, at least proved to be helpful

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I can't see how an image provides more clarity than "returned no rows".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a record when your search does not match anything

You can achieve this result using `UNION` operator, to add to your result set the default row you desire when main search give no results:

```
declare @src varchar(50) = '3'

Select column1, column2, column3
from table1
where column1 = @src

UNION ALL

Select 'no rows found', null column2, null column3
where not exists (select null from table1 where column1 = @src)
```

you can write it using cte for readability

```
declare @src varchar(50) = '3'

;with
src as (
    Select column1, column2, column3
    from table1
    where column1 = @src
)
    select * from src

    UNION ALL

    Select 'no rows found', null column2, null column3
    where not exists (select null from src)
```

Comment: CTE is a good approach

Comment: thanks for this easy-to-follow answer, it works!

Comment: I have updated the answer, you should use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. The difference is that if you have the same row in both queries, with `UNION` you will get only one of them, in short words it adds a `GROUP BY` on all fields.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers require reading from the table multiple times. It is possible to do this with only reading once from the table

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  column1,
  column2,
  column3
FROM (
    SELECT
      column1,
      column2,
      column3,
      1 AS Ordering
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.column1 = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      'no rows found',
      NULL,
      NULL,
      2
) t
ORDER BY Ordering;
```

Note that there should be no actual sorting involved, as the compiler can see that different unique values come out of each part of the union.

Comment: Does the cte answer also read from the following table twice?

Comment: Yes, CTEs are compiled as if they were derived subqueries, so it comes to the same thing.